# selectNodes function of ActiveXObject does not work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

I am trying to get this piece of code written in Javascript to work in IE 11. But when I try to access the length of the node it gives me 0. I am not sure why the below code is not able to find out the `<somenode>` node in XML. Does anyone have any idea?

```
try { 
  doc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
  var xml_string = '<somenode><child>Hello</child></somenode>
                    <somenode><child>good bye</child></somenode>';
  doc.loadXML(xml_string); 
  doc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
  var node = doc.selectNodes("/somenode");
  console.log("node is "+node.length);
} 
catch (e) 
{   
  console.log("inside catch"+e); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: Your XML doesn't have a root element.  I've added `<xml>` as the root.

```
try { 
  doc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
  var xml_string = '<xml><somenode><child>Hello</child></somenode>
                    <somenode><child>good bye</child></somenode></xml>';
  doc.loadXML(xml_string); 
  doc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
  var node = doc.selectNodes("/xml/somenode");
  console.log("node is "+node.length);
} 
catch (e) 
{   
  console.log("inside catch"+e); 
}
```

Comment: @WillamWalseth <xml/> at the start is een empty element

Comment: Thanks, fixed in the sample.